# How do I make an UIImage/-View with rounded corners CGRect (Swift)

Tags: uiimageview, swift, rounded-corners, swift-playground

How do I make a UIImageView with rounded corners on a Swift iOS Playground?
Inside it needs to be filled with a color.

Comment: You can also Rounded particular edge : https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2018/02/how-to-set-roundcorner-radius-on-view.html

Answer (score 191, accepted):

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: what if we want to round the UIImage not UIImageView ????

Comment: If you round the ImageView, the image will appear round. Same result.

Comment: @Arslan, see [stackoverflow.com/questions/70252577](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70252577), if you want to round the UIImage, rather than the UIImageView.

Answer (score 30):

For rounded circle image frame in swift, what it worked for me was:

```
self.profileImageView.image =  UIImage(named:"profileUser")
self.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImageView.frame.size.width / 2
self.profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

And for adding a shadow:

```
self.profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
self.profileImageView.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0);
self.profileImageView.shadowRadius = 5;
self.profileImageView.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
```

Answer (score 23):

Try this, it worked for me.

```
self.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImageView.frame.size.width / 2
self.profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 14):

I was tired of writing *set radius and mask to bound* for each UIView. So I made the following extenstion for UIView. Should work for every UIView subclass, though I have not tested it. The extension can be narrowed down for specific Views you use of course.

```
extension UIView {      
    func setRadius(radius: CGFloat? = nil) {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = radius ?? self.frame.width / 2;
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    }
}
```

It will default to the view's half width if you don't pass it any specific value.

Answer (score 10):

Swift 3.0, 4.0

If you want to use the storyboard.
I applied this and make sure that "Clip to bounds" is enable.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have an option to round each `UIImageView`, you can copy this code into your project without forgetting to check `clip to bounds` and set its value to `true`

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
extension UIImageView
{
    private struct AssociatedKey
    {
        static var rounded = "UIImageView.rounded"
    }

    @IBInspectable var rounded: Bool
    {
        get
        {
            if let rounded = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKey.rounded) as? Bool
            {
                return rounded
            }
            else
            {
                return false
            }
        }
        set
        {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKey.rounded, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
            layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(newValue ? 1.0 : 0.0)*min(bounds.width, bounds.height)/2
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Work perfectly, Thanks

Comment: you can also add `self.clipsToBounds = true` in the setter to not have to worry about setting it in the interface builder

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5.0:**

My personal preference is to have an extra swift file for specific changes like this one. What I do is then create a class e.g. "RoundCorner" which is a subclass of the element I want to change in this case a View element. And then I am overriding the individual settings.

```
class RoundCorner: UIView {
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 10 // change this number to get the corners you want
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

After that, you only have to select the element you want this changes on, and set the custom class to the class we created earlier.

[Look at the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7aDp.png)

Answer (score 1):

Setting **layer.cornerRadius = 10** at **User Defined Runtime Attributes** section on the Identity inspector works even on repeatable elements like table cells.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4 you can do it fairly easily like this:

```
yourUIImage.layer.cornerRadius = 10 // Set it how you prefer
yourUIImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

And if you use a rather long rectangle image, for example for a featured content part in your app or whatever, make sure the `Content Mode` is set to `Scale To Fit` because otherwise the corners will be somehow rounded but will cut badly and it will not be a perfect round corner but rather a rounded, then sharp cut where it clips.

Comment: UIImage, dont even have layer...

Answer (score 0):

in your viewDidload add this line of code

```
self.headerImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.headerImageView.frame.size.width / 2
```