# Rounded bars in ios Charts

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I've created a BarChart using `BarChartView` from [ios-Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) but I can't figure out howto add rounded corners to bars.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
let barChart: BarChartView
//...
var xVals = [String]()
var yVals = [BarChartDataEntry]()
//...

let set1 = BarChartDataSet(yVals: yVals, label: "Label")

set1.drawValuesEnabled = false
set1.highlightLineWidth = 3
set1.colors = [UIColor.whiteColor()]

barChart.data = BarChartData(xVals: xVals, dataSet: set1)
```

I've looked for a property like `set1.barCornerRadius` to set, but I didn't find anything.

Here is **what I have**:

[image: squared bar]

Here is **what I need**:

[image: rounded bar]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25476139/how-do-i-make-an-uiimage-view-with-rounded-corners-cgrect-swift ?

Comment: No @oren, bars are managed directly by the BarChartView. By default they are squared [like these](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/78b4bc4e50e151970961daf56e81c4c0db72d27c/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f5068696c4a61792f4d5043686172742f6d61737465722f73637265656e73686f74732f73696d706c6564657369676e5f6261726368617274332e706e67) and I don't know howto round their corners.

Comment: Ok, sorry... I just thought that after all, this is a UIView, so maybe possible to use its layer...

Comment: check out https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/1066. There are demo code, you can try first

Answer (score 42):

In `BarChartRenderer.swift` you can to modify `open func drawDataSet(context: CGContext, dataSet: IBarChartDataSet, index: Int)`

Then there's `if-statement` for stacked and nonstacked bars, choose your case and remove:

```
context.fill(barRect)
```

and instead of it add:

```
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: barRect, cornerRadius: %YOUR_CORNER_RADIUS%)
context.addPath(bezierPath.cgPath)

context.drawPath(using: .fill)
```

Comment: I've tried to override `drawDataSet` but I got dozen of errors that property is inaccessible due to `fileprivate` protection level. Do I have to copy them(and their init methods) into my subclass, or is there a better solution?

Comment: i  implemented your code in my file ,but this file is not called , so what is the problem is that?

Comment: If you just want to round the upper corners:             let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:barRect,byRoundingCorners:[.topRight, .topLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5, height:  5))

Comment: Replace Line 434 if you have confusion

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to wait for [this pull request](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/pull/3754) to be merged in the original library, there's a working solution that I use myself in a couple of projects.

This working example is based on all of the previous data I've collected all over the Internet. It works as of today but you have to do a few precautions before using it.

To make it work, all you have to do is replace the whole `BarChartRenderer.swift` file [with this one](https://gist.github.com/ShadeApps/9285904fc716dbe6c13c6fbff23ab27e).

First, have a backup copy of the original file. Then, make sure you replace the file every time you update your Charts CocoaPod, otherwise, the file will be overwritten.

In the end, to control the corner radius of your chart, just change the `barCornerRadius = CGFloat(5.0)` to whatever you want to.

Here's the final result I've got:

[image]

After you've replaced the file, make sure to clean your Xcode's build folder and then recompile your project for changes to take effect immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this feature is currently not supported but [is under development](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/1066). In the meanwhile take a look at [this pull request](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/pull/1917).

Comment: nope, the link is wrong. Correct is https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/1066

Comment: Is this feature still under development? If not, please consider updating your answer As to the link to the pull request, whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information.

Comment: The issue and the related PR are still open

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to round the edges:

1. You have to change in Charts library,  Go to the BarchartRenderer.swift
   and unlock the file
2. Line No: 434 comment/remove it.
3. Add this below code

```
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: barRect, cornerRadius:3.2)
context.addPath(bezierPath.cgPath)
context.drawPath(using: .fill)
```

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score 0):

I did it and it was successful

== modify "BarChartRenderer"

```
class MyBarChartRenderer: BarChartRenderer {
override func drawDataSet(context: CGContext, dataSet: BarChartDataSetProtocol, index: Int) {
    guard let barDataProvider = dataProvider else { return }
    let trans = barDataProvider.getTransformer(forAxis: dataSet.axisDependency)
    var barRectBuffer = CGRect()
    
    context.saveGState()
    
    context.beginTransparencyLayer(auxiliaryInfo: .none)
    
    for i in stride(from: dataSet.entryCount - 1, through: 0, by: -1) {
        guard let e = dataSet.entryForIndex(i) as? BarChartDataEntry else { continue }
        
        let x = e.x
        let y = e.y
        let left = x - 0.5
        let right = x + 0.5
        let top = y >= 0.0 ? y : 0.0
        let bottom = y <= 0.0 ? y : 0.0
        
        barRectBuffer.origin.x = CGFloat(left)
        barRectBuffer.size.width = CGFloat(right - left)
        barRectBuffer.origin.y = CGFloat(top)
        barRectBuffer.size.height = CGFloat(bottom - top)
        
        trans.rectValueToPixel(&barRectBuffer)
        
        let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 10.0
        let originalWidth = barRectBuffer.size.width
        let modifiedWidth = 0.25 * originalWidth
        
        let xOffset = (originalWidth - modifiedWidth) / 2.0
        
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: barRectBuffer.origin.x + xOffset,
                                                    y: barRectBuffer.origin.y,
                                                    width: modifiedWidth,
                                                    height: barRectBuffer.size.height),
                                cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath
        context.addPath(path)
        context.closePath()
        
        context.setFillColor(dataSet.color(atIndex: i).cgColor)
        
        context.drawPath(using: .fill)
    }
    
    context.endTransparencyLayer()
    
    context.restoreGState()
}
```

}

=== Use it!

```
 let customRenderer = MyBarChartRenderer(dataProvider: myBarChart,
                                            animator: myBarChart.chartAnimator,
                                            viewPortHandler: myBarChart.viewPortHandler)
    myBarChart.renderer = customRenderer
```

Comment: Thanks for posting complete example code. It would be nice and fair to leave a reference to @keyv's solution ;-)