# Creating custom iOS-Charts renderer

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I'm using [iOS-Charts library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/), and I need to subclass `HorizontalBarChartRenderer` so that I can change implementation of `drawDataSet(...)`. This should be possible as stated before, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37945463/2374802).

So I created my custom renderer, but because of access control and because I'm using Cocoapods I had to override little more than just `drawDataSet`:

- fileprivate class Buffer
- fileprivate var _buffers = Buffer
- fileprivate func prepareBuffer(dataSet: IBarChartDataSet, index: Int)
- fileprivate var _barShadowRectBuffer: CGRect = CGRect() open override
- open override func drawDataSet(context: CGContext, dataSet: IBarChartDataSet,
  index: Int)

I didn't change anything yet, above methods were just copied from `HorizontalBarChartRenderer`, and I set renderer like this:

```
self.horizontalBarView.renderer = HorizontalBarStackRenderer(dataProvider: self.horizontalBarView, animator: self.horizontalBarView.chartAnimator, viewPortHandler: self.horizontalBarView.viewPortHandler).
```

When I try to run it, I get `fatal error: Index out of range` at `BarCharRenderer's drawValues()`:

```
let buffer = _buffers[dataSetIndex]
```

When I tried to set renderer to standard `HorizontalBarChartRenderer` the same way:

```
self.horizontalBarView.renderer = HorizontalBarChartRenderer(dataProvider: self.horizontalBarView, animator: self.horizontalBarView.chartAnimator, viewPortHandler: self.horizontalBarView.viewPortHandler)
```

everything works fine. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally know what was the issue, my subclass didn't override `drawValues()` method, as it wasn't explicit that it is needed. Moreover, this method is accessing variable `shouldDrawValues`  which is internal and therefor can't be accessed outside the module. I commented out the part where it's used for now, but I'll have to somehow mimic it on my own.

Comment: hi, can I ask how you override `drawValues`?...I'm trying to do the same for `PieChartRenderer`, but I don't honestly know where to start..thanks!

Comment: In my subclass of renderer, I just put the copy of default `drawValues()` and adjusted it to my needs.

Comment: were you able to access shouldDrawValues ?

Answer (score 4):

How I made it work for bar charts:

Your custom renderer:

```
class RoundedBarChartRenderer: BarChartRenderer {

    private class Buffer {
       var rects = [CGRect]()
    }

    private var _buffers = [Buffer]()

    private var _barShadowRectBuffer: CGRect = CGRect()

    override func initBuffers() { /* copy everything from original file */ }

    override func drawDataSet(context: CGContext, dataSet: IBarChartDataSet, index: Int)
        { /* Copy everything */ }

    private func prepareBuffer(dataSet: IBarChartDataSet, index: Int)  { /* copy everything */ }

    override func drawValues(context: CGContext) { /* Copy everything */ }
}
```

Some parts will still not work properly, like accessibility. Comment out those part. Also, don't use any `super.METHOD_NAME()`