# Rounded corners of UILabel swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, cornerradius

I am creating a `UILabel` programatically. But the below piece of code doesn't give me rounded corners. I think I am missing out something very basic.

```
var textLabel:UILabel? =  UILabel()
textLabel?.text = text
textLabel?.frame = CGRect(x:point.x, y:point.y, width:(textLabel?.intrinsicContentSize.width)!, height:15)
textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
textLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"OpenSans", size:8)
textLabel?.sizeToFit()
textLabel?.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make an UIImage/-View with rounded corners CGRect (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25476139/how-do-i-make-an-uiimage-view-with-rounded-corners-cgrect-swift)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I think you should set maskToBounds for textLabel. try this:

```
textLabel?.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 13):

**swift 4.2**

set label **corner radius**.
Try this.....

```
labelVerified.layer.cornerRadius = 6
labelVerified.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 12):

try this :-

```
textLabel?.layer.cornerRadius = textLabel?.frame.size.height/2.0

textLabel?.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

if you want to set border color then :-

```
  textLabel?.layer.borderColor = .red.cgColor
  textLabel?.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
```

Comment: the questioner already mentioned the size `layer.cornerRadius = 20.0`

Comment: it is for when you want to accurate corners then use this. if size if greater then height then it will not resize in perfect shape. or you can use  constant value as you needed.

Answer (score 8):

set `masksToBounds` for your label

> masksToBounds act as a Boolean indicating whether sublayers are clipped to the layer’s bounds.

```
textLabel?.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
textLabel?.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

refer apple [documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/masksToBounds).

Answer (score 4):

try this :

```
yourLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
yourLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
yourLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
yourLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
```

this should give you the rounded borders

The key is the property "maskToBounds" that is a Boolean indicating whether sublayers are clipped to the layer’s bounds.