# How can I space out the borders from the image?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, constraints

How can I make the borders to be a little bit more away from the image and not be directly attached to it like you can see at the screenshot
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make an UIImage/-View with rounded corners CGRect (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25476139/how-do-i-make-an-uiimage-view-with-rounded-corners-cgrect-swift)

Answer (score 1):

In order to have rounded corners you have to set

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 9 //Or any other number
```

In order to make the borders further from the borders just change your constraints' values.

Comment: I suppose OP knows about this since he calls method called `roundImage()`. Anyway, question is very unclear and problem is probably connected with mask to bounds / clips to bounds set to `false` instead of `true`

Comment: I dont understand what masksToBounds is

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39466262/10408872 check this link let me know if it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: I dont understand what masksToBounds is

Comment: Here is detail information about it. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410896-maskstobounds

Comment: I don't understand that

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand the question correctly but you might be looking for something like:

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```